# RabbitMQ in open source ESB

Tags: rabbitmq, esb

Does any open source ESB support RabbitMQ out of the box?
It seems that apache camel based ESB works with Apache Qpid non RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) has support for [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) based AMQP Transport. [This](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport) documentation explains on how to configure this RabbitMQ based AMQP transport. Some samples also included in that document itself to try out.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.12 Camel now has a [rabbitmq component](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html).